# @Html.DisplayText will not actually display text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

The following is the first  section in the first row of a table on one of my ASP MVC3 Index pages. I've stepped through the code when that page loads, and can see that the evaluation of the conditions is done properly, however not of the "CE" or "PT" displays. I'm pretty new to ASP MVC, can someone help me with the syntax/explain what's going on?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Where(i => i.Status != "C")) {
var Id = item.Id;
<tr>
    <td>
    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.TableName))
    {
        if (item.TableName.Equals("AgentContEd"))
        {
            @Html.DisplayText("CE");
        }
        else if (item.TableName.Equals("AgentProductTraining"))
        {
            @Html.DisplayText("PT");
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TableName)
        }             
    }           
    </td>
```

Comment: Have you tried @Html.Raw("CE"); or just replacing the statement with the raw text?  Are CE and PT attributes on your model?

Comment: Using @Html.Raw worked. I was under the impression you could place a string value insinde the DisplayText (). Is this not the case?

Comment: The DisplayText is synonomous for Model.PropertyName.. so Model.PropertyName = @Html.DisplayText('PropertyName')

Comment: You can replace @Html.Raw("CE") with just CE

Comment: No, you cannot just replace `@Html.Raw("CE")` with just CE since it's inside server side code. See my answer

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use `@:` or `<text></text>` to specify html text inside a server side code if you do not have any other html in there.

```
if (item.TableName.Equals("AgentContEd"))
{
    @:CE
}
else if (item.TableName.Equals("AgentProductTraining"))
{
    <text>PT</text>
}
```

Answer (score 19):

There are like 5 different ways of displaying text. 
In order to display a string you need to use

```
@Html.DisplayName(string)
```

Comment: Really wish I knew why `DisplayText` didn't work but this does

Comment: See answer from Justin Bicknell, DisplayText should actually be called DisplayDisplayTextFor

Answer (score 13):

The `DisplayText` is synonymous with `Model.PropertyName`, so `Model.PropertyName = @Html.DisplayText('PropertyName')`

So if CE is not an attribute of your model, and you are just trying to output raw text than just replace that statement with the raw text:

```
        if (item.TableName.Equals("AgentContEd"))
        {
            <text>CE</text>
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to get Razor to realize that you are trying to display literal text. See this good
[Razor syntax guide](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) for more information.

`if (item.TableName.Equals("AgentContEd"))
    {
        <text>CE</text>
    }`