# " [ " doesn't show from @Html.DisplayText( " [ " ) , web page doesn't reflect this html code

Tags: html, razor

Given this html code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CountryName, new  { placeholder = "Country", @class = "input-medium", customerui = "Country" }) 
@Html.DisplayText( " [ " )                     
@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.CountryName )      
@Html.DisplayText( " ] " )                     
@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.CountryFootnote)
```

The expectation is that the following would be shown:

- *input textbox*   **[ VC ]** Saint Vincent and The Grenadines

But instead the " [ " and " ] " are missing?

---

[image: page shown from above code]

---

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the character codes. `[` = `&#91;` `]` = `&#93;`. Never used Razor though.

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387396/html-displaytext-will-not-actually-display-text

Comment: The answer to your question is the second one in the link posted by @AndrewKarpov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did search last night and did not find [@Html.DisplayText will not actually display text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387396/html-displaytext-will-not-actually-display-text)
Which explains my posting this question.

The helpful answer is:

The DisplayText is synonomous for Model.PropertyName.. so Model.PropertyName = @Html.DisplayText('PropertyName')

So if ' [ ' and ' ] ' are not attributes of your model and you are just trying to output raw text then just replace the 'DisplayText' statements with the raw text:

```
            <text> [ </text>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.CountryName )
            <text> ] </text>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can switch from MVC Razor code back to RAW HTML with `@:` so this should work:

```
    @:[@Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.CountryName )]
```