# User.Identity.GetUserName() return wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I'm not quite sure what is wrong with this simple code in Razor view :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
<span>@Html.DisplayName(User.Identity.GetUserName())</span>
```

I have checked the value in my `AspNetUsers` table field `UserName` and it is `xxx@example.com`.

Instead, return `xxx@example.com`, it just returns `com`.

For sake of curiosity, I have change it to `xxx@example.net`, indeed it just returns `net`.

I have tried to search for some articles and found nothing. What is actually wrong with that code?

Comment: Why are you putting it through `Html.DisplayName`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I tried search the question again but didnt found it, from what I read before, it is using `Html.DisplayName`

Comment: @John it is not duplicated, even I am using `Html.Label` still return `com`

Comment: You're using functions designed for obtaining names for *model fields* and controls. Stop wrapping it in *any* `Html.Something` functions.

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't that be *User.Identity.Name*?

Comment: @Colour Don't use code from the question. Use code from the answer. 

Comment: Thank you, I get it from 2nd answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387396/html-displaytext-will-not-actually-display-text , I thought it will display string

Comment: @John, the accepted answer `@Html.DisplayFor` can not be used in this case since it is not a model, even `@Html.Display` return blank. After tries the second answer `@Html.encode` do the trick, but is this really for diplaying text not for encoding url?

Comment: And `@User.Identity.GetUserName()`, as suggested by the accepted answer (changed to your use case), doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you just want to display the value of 'User Name' that is available under identity, whats the use of `DisplayName` here? Display name method try to find the attribute `display` available on the nested property you passed in to method.

And do you remember how these MVC method works?? whenever we pass any expression in such methods it treat it as nested property and try to find the last property node.

example for `c.User.Name` it will try to use the `name` so when we passing `xxx@example.net` it try to find the last property in nested expression that is `xx@example.net` and value will be `net`.

But when you just wanted to display value just use

```
<span>@User.Identity.GetUserName()</span>
```

Comment: glad it helped.. do remember the 2nd para I specified and you will never get to this problem.

Comment: I get it now, so `DisplayName` looking for `.net` property name which `net`. thank you